# How to read input() from a text file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

My Python program requests some user input:

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(n):
    s = input()
    # ...
```

For debugging purposes, I would like to create a test input.txt file like this:

```
3
string1
string2
string3
```

so that I need not to manually enter data from the keyboard every time I launch it for debug.

Is there any way to get `input()` from text file, not from keyboard (without changing program code).

I am using Wing Personal as a dev tool.

**Update**

I know for sure, that there exist bots which are able to test python programs passing various inputs and comparing output with known answers. I guess these bots do not hit the keyboard with iron fingers. Maybe they use command-line tools to pass `input.txt` to the Python so that it reads `input()` from that file, not from keyboard. I would like to learn how to do it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Input reads from Standard input so if you use bash you can redirect stdin to a file

without changing your code

in bash you would run something like

```
cat textfile | programm.py
```

or

```
< textfile programm.py
```

Comment: OP asked for python?

Comment: he also asks (without changing program code). so i provided a method for changing standard input without touching the code

Comment: standing your ground, I like it!

Comment: I think you meant, `cat textfile | python programm.py`

Answer (score 8):

I've noticed that none of these solutions redirects the stdin from Python. To do that, you can use this snippet:

```
import sys
sys.stdin = open('input.txt', 'r')
```

Hopefully, that helps you!

Answer (score 1):

You can read the file into a list like this:

```
 with open('filename.txt', 'r') as file:
     input_lines = [line.strip() for line in file]
```

s would be data in index i.

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(n):
    s = input_lines[i]
    # ...
```

**Make sure your py file is in the same dir as your txt file.**

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `test.py` file which is used to run your test. In the `test.py`, you will read the content of `input.txt` and import the programming.

For example, in `test.py` file.

```py
import main_code
with open('input.txt', 'r') as file:
   lines = file.readlines()

for line in lines:
   s = line

"""
working with the input.
"""
```