# Pass a list to a function instead of user-input - Jupiter

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, user-input

My function gets input from user. I want to call it in a way that it gets input from list - without changing function. I am using Jupyter notebook - Python

```
def example_function() :

 a = input()
 b = input()
 print (a+b)
 c = input()
 d = input()
 print (c+d)

 return
```

I want to call `example_function` and pass a list to it as input values (a, b, c and d). It is not possible to change `example_function` itself.

Comment: the only way to do this without changing `example_function` is to override the `input` function, which you should not do.

Comment: If you are able to edit `example_function`, you can override `input` in that scope, but still, it would be better to actually change the function

Comment: "I want to fundamentally change the way my function works without changing it" is not a very clear task. Your function takes no arguments, so you can't pass anything into it without changing that fact. You could define the list outside the function and use `global` to access it from within the function, but that requires adding to the function. Perhaps if you clarify why you don't want to change it, or what specific parts of it you don't want to change, that might help. As it stands, this seems like an [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read input() from a text file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59159460/how-to-read-input-from-a-text-file-in-python)

Comment: what do you mean "I want to call it in a way that it gets input from list"?

Comment: @ArefehYavary can you please explain why you don't want to change `example_function`?

Comment: @Samathingamajig I dont have access to it

Comment: " without changing function" the function as written takes no arguments, there is no way you can pass arguments to it without changing it. What you could do is monkey patch stdin

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by temporarily changing `stdin` which is where the `input()` function gets its data:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
from io import StringIO
import sys


@contextmanager
def redirect_stdin(source):
    save_stdin = sys.stdin
    sys.stdin = StringIO('\n'.join(source)+'\n')
    yield
    sys.stdin = save_stdin

def example_function():
    a = input()
    b = input()
    print(a+b)
    c = input()
    d = input()
    print(c+d)
    return


inp = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

with redirect_stdin(inp):
    example_function()
```

Output:

```
ab
cd
```

Comment: when I'm using this code, it still waiting for an input, doesn't using inp.

Comment: It worked OK when I tested it, but I just now noticed there was no newline on the last string, so have modified it to add one to it, too. Try it again.

Comment: I tried it again, but still doesnt work for me. It is waiting for input. I am using Jupiter.

Comment: Jupiter's an entirely different ballgame. You should mention such details when asking questions here. You will likely have to do something specific for it.

Comment: mentioned @martineau

Comment: Better late than never.  ;¬) The only problem is your script won't work unless it's run with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
def get_inputs():
  a = input()
  b = input()
  c = input()
  d = input()
  return (a, b, c, d)

def example_function(a, b, c, d):
  print(a + b)
  print(c + d)
  return

example_function(*get_inputs())
```

Or more literally what you asked for, passing a list:

```py
def get_inputs():
  a = input()
  b = input()
  c = input()
  d = input()
  return [a, b, c, d]

def example_function(inputs):
  a = inputs[0]
  b = inputs[1]
  c = inputs[2]
  d = inputs[3]
  print(a + b)
  print(c + d)
  return

example_function(get_inputs())
```

Comment: this is the opposite of what they're asking for

Comment: I can't imagine what the opposite of this looks like, but I am curious what you think they were asking for (it was very unclear)

Comment: They are trying to use `example_function` with a list, but without modifying `example_function` at all

Comment: yes, it's a seemingly self-contradictory request that can be interpreted many ways...

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's necessary to change the function here because it doesn't have any arguments currently. Here's one way to do the function so it works like you described.

```
def example_function(list):

counter = 0
for i in list:
    counter = counter +1
    if (counter == 1 or counter == 3):
        print(list[i] + list[i -1])
```

Comment: I dont have to change the function. If I can change it, answer is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

With absolutely no changes to your `example_function` function, the only way I'd know is to change the global `input`. You should also reset it after so that the rest of your script works. this can be done by creating another method.

```py
def example_function():
  a = input()
  b = input()
  print (a+b)
  c = input()
  d = input()
  print (c+d)
  return

def call_example_function(list):
  global input
  _input = input
  index = 0
  def input(*args, **kwargs):
    nonlocal index
    ret = list[index]
    index += 1
    return str(ret) # the normal input will always return a string
  example_function()
  input = _input

if __name__ == "__main__":
  name = input("What's your name?")
  print(name)
  call_example_function(["aa", "bb", "cc", "dd"])
  pet = input("What pet do you have") # input works as normal outside
  print(pet)
```

Output:

```py
aabb
ccdd
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bVJLasMwEIUufYpBXdR2Umihi1AwpdA7dBGCGEuyLSpLRpab5CzdZNP2Tj1N9alDQ7IR897MvDca6eNr2LvO6MPhc3LN7ern6oGLBsQO-0EJ2kyaOWl0XjxmAAgVSD1MLi88qk_QYKV2kOOiDoid5PilSrbgAVnhJquzLLgyVIqeWSs5umjfKlOjSkoe0hjM0p6Qmoudx3fB0sslyxJtOy6hLN-2IYpKANpoZVhU802R8pP45uC2juQmskl0UcH9XOTHhdHZ3IcFXIPrhFez_TwZbKVSgGqL-3Eux9AgdeslzjcbJ083SVfKMtkApRp7QSlUFRBKe5SaUhKGD_xxoeS1Q3czwt5MNmaeyHHHecDxNS7udU0QyRJIXYeTsXByTjaxX7hTi8hwE3ygw3fxz8VnivR5_v7Q4fu5ZtmLaRP8BQ)

Comment: I dont have to change the function. If I can change it, answer is trivial.

Comment: @ArefehYavary this is without changing the function. `call_example_function` is an additional function that calls `example_function` inside of it, after setting `input`, and then after `example_function` is done, it resets `input`